# Issue with loop in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I a variable in my `Jenkinsfile` that contains a list of URLs and i would like a be able to run over them. When i pass the variable $URL to the function, I get an error:

```
No such property: $URL for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

However, I'm able to echo this variable with `sh`.

```
pipeline {
        agent any
        environment {
            URL="https://www.aaa.com," \
            + "https://www.bbb.com," \
            + "https://www.ccc.com"
        }
        stages {
            stage ('A') {
                //...
            }
            stage ('B') {
                //...
            }
            stage ('C') {
                steps {
                    script {
                        sh 'echo $URL'
                        funcion($URL)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }



    def funcion(URL) {
        sh "echo Going to echo a list"
        for (int i = 0; i < URL.size(); i++) {
            sh "echo ${URL[i]}"
        }
    }
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass this variable to the `funcion()` method as

```
function(URL)
```

instead of

```
funcion($URL)
```

The dollar sign `$` is used only inside the `GString` when you want to interpolate a variable. For instance

```
#!groovy

def name = "Joe"
println "My name is $name"
```

results in

```
My name is Joe
```

You can read more about string interpolation in the Groovy documentation - http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation

Comment: Thanks. Now i get a long error starting with `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'loop' found among steps`.

Comment: It says exactly that - you are trying to call an unexisting method `loop` in your pipeline script. It has nothing to do with the error you mentioned earlier. Analyze your code step by step and check why you are calling such a method. Maybe you made a typo or something like that.